# Install Ubuntu over pxe with an usb-C network adaptator

Tags: boot, networking, kernel, pxe, overlayfs

I want to install Ubuntu over pxe.

With my Thinkpad it works fine. But my Dell doesn't have an Rj45 connector, so I use an usb-C network adaptor.

In the startup process, initramfs don't get an IP because it doesn't see a network interface.

I tried recompiling the kernel and with `menuconfig` I enabled RTK drivers. The DHCP works fine, and it's trying to download my linux.iso but it shows this message:

```
/cow format specified as 'overlay' and no support found
```

I checked in `menuconfig` and overlay is enabled.

With <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> installation begins with this error:

```
no root file system is defined
```

and freezes.